# Python URLLib does not work with PyQt + Multiprocessing

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-multiprocessing

A simple code as such:

```
import urllib2
import requests

from PyQt4 import QtCore

import multiprocessing
import time

data = (
    ['a', '2'], 
)

def mp_worker((inputs, the_time)):
    r = requests.get('http://www.gpsbasecamp.com/national-parks')
    request = urllib2.Request("http://www.gpsbasecamp.com/national-parks")
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    p.map(mp_worker, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp_handler()
```

Basically, if i import PyQt4, and i have a urllib request (i believe this is used in almost all web extraction libraries such as BeautifulSoup, Requests or Pyquery. it crashes with a cryptic log on my MAC)

Comment: that's not the bug. this code runs fine if i remove the import pqt4

Comment: the issue is that no network request library can work if it's run under a seperate process while pyqt4 is imported. ive tried them all

Comment: This code works fine on Ubuntu and on Windows with Python2.7 installs.

Comment: you are right..i tried on ubuntu. this works. ah well..looks like i have to switch my dev over to ubuntu then

Comment: You should use PyQt as it's meant to be used: not with multiprocessing but with its own inherit QThreads, QThreadPools and QRunnables (or QtConcurrent).

That would fix your issue.

Comment: Have you tried with [urllib3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urllib3)?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly True. It always fails on Mac, I have wasted rows of days just to fix this. And honestly there is no fix as of now. The best way is to use Thread instead of Process and it will work like a charm.

By the way -

```
r = requests.get('http://www.gpsbasecamp.com/national-parks')
```

and

```
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.gpsbasecamp.com/national-parks")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

do one and the same thing. Why are you doing it twice?

Comment: I spoke to some folks on an IRC channel. it seems this combination will not work on the stock python version of OSX. I will have to recompile my own version of python for this to work.

Comment: i know..i was just testing both

Comment: is there an alternative apart from switching to ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due `_scproxy.get_proxies()` not being fork-safe on Mac.

This is raised here https://bugs.python.org/issue33725#msg329926

> _scproxy has been known to be problematic for some time, see for instance Issue31818.  That issue also gives a simple workaround: setting urllib's "no_proxy" environment variable to "*" will prevent the calls to the System Configuration framework.

This is something that urllib may be attempting to do causing failure when multiprocessing.

There is a workaround and that is to set the environmental variable `no-proxy` to `*`

Eg. `export no_proxy=*`